# Как удалить из строки 1+ подряд идущих звездочек

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью рег выражений удалить из строки две подряд звездочки? А лучше "если больше чем одна подряд". Строка у меня находится в переменной `$string`.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Две звездочки подряд можно удалить и без регулярного выражения. Или вам только две, а если, например, три подряд, то уже не трогать их?

Comment: Дополните вопрос конкретными примерами того (что было) и соответственно (что надо получить)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот эта строка удалит все звездочки рядом если их больше одного:

```
$str = '*******dsxdgdsg*dfdsfds**sdfsdfsdf*sdfsdf***sdfsfsdf';
$str = preg_replace('/\*{2,}/', '', $str);
print_r($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '*******';
$str = preg_replace('/\*\*/', '', $str);
```